# Flask can't load css file

Tags: jquery, python, html, css, flask

I have a problem with the template below: the CSS file is not loaded.

I placed "style.css" in "my_project/static/" properly.

I just tried to replace `<link rel=stylesheet ...>` in the source code of the HTML file with the code of "style.css" and it works.

What is the problem?

```
<!doctype html>
<title>{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock %} | MiniTwit</title>
<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{  url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">

<div class=page>
  <h1>MiniTwit</h1>
  <div class=navigation>
  {% if g.user %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('timeline') }}">my timeline</a> |
    <a href="{{ url_for('public_timeline') }}">public timeline</a> |
    <a href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">sign out [{{ g.user.username }}]</a>
  {% else %}
<a href="{{ url_for('public_timeline') }}">public timeline</a> |
<a href="{{ url_for('register') }}">sign up</a> |
<a href="{{ url_for('login') }}">sign in</a>
  {% endif %}
  </div>
  {% with flashes = get_flashed_messages() %}
    {% if flashes %}
      <ul class=flashes>
      {% for message in flashes %}
        <li>{{ message }}
      {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    {% endif %}
  {% endwith %}
  <div class=body>
  {% block body %}{% endblock %}
  </div>
  <div class=footer>
    MiniTwit &mdash; A Flask Application
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: why do you have a div outside the body? - is that a python thing?

Comment: Please post a minimal example of your application folder structure and your application config. This smells like Flask isn't resolving the path to your static files correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You should put double quotes around attributes' values in your `link` tag and put this tag inside the `head` tag:

```
<head>
<title>{% block title %}Welcome{% endblock %} | MiniTwit</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{  url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">
</head>
```

And also close your `html` tag at the end of your html file.

Comment: I already did this but It didn't work. And the code that I wrote above is a sample code in some book about web programming with Flask.